# Date format from deserialized json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datetime, deserialization

I was trying to fix an issue of date format. Date format can change based on CultureInfo chosen by user (it will mainly be French or English GB one) and data is inside a json. Here is the code :

```
string json = @"{
    ""answers"": [
        {
        ""answer"": ""01/08/2022 11:30:00"",
        ""typeForm"": ""Date"",
        ""dateToString"": ""01/08/2022 11:30:00""
        }
    ]
}";

dynamic temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

dynamic OnBoardingQuestions = temp.answers;

CultureInfo ciUS = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
string dateStringUS = ((DateTime)OnBoardingQuestions[0].answer).ToString("G", ciUS);
DateTime dateStringConverted = DateTime.Parse(dateStringUS, ci);
```

Date format inside `answer` is the French one so and `ci` is the user CultureInfo (French CultureInfo).

So basically I convert date inside my json into a string with US date format parameters, then convert it again into a DateTime with the user date format.

This surprisingly works, correct values are put into every `dateStringConverted` DateTime fields.

Would some of you have some explanation why this works? And is there anything I should be aware of that could cause some trouble elsewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: As you are in control of the json, do apply the ISO format for DateTime text expressions. Then you can skip all this back and forth converting between cultures.

Comment: Why use `dynamic`, why not use a proper object model?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Ok so I just realized my front could send two kinds of formats to the API: ISO 8601 or general date long time ("G") format specifier. I will fix that, that should solve most of my issues. I did not send the json entirely since I'm not the owner of the project. I joined the team recently and the project is quite old. As I can see dynamic is used because some fields could be a string or an array of strings. So yes it could have been an object model.